# Github: new PR includes commits earlier than fork

Tags: github

I'm only learning Github. I have a question about the web interface, and would prefer answers for the web interface, *if they are possible*.

I forked a repo that I want to contribute to. I create a new branch on my fork, make a couple of commits, and now I'm trying to create the PR on the original repo. This is what it looks like:

[image: while creating my PR on Github]

My selection of the base and head branches is made following the guidelines for this particular project. I'm supposed to put bugfixes in the `hotfix` branch.

Now, since my fork was made only on the beginning of October, what I don't understand are those 4 commits made by someone else, not me, on earlier dates. I only did the 2 commits on Oct 10. I expected anything previous to be exactly the same as on the original.

**My questions:**

1. What is going on? Why are those earlier commits showing there in the compare?
2. How can I remove them, or how should I create a PR with only my own commits?

I've had this problem before and it caused my PR not to be accepted, so I really need to understand this and correct it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my own question: the problem was at the moment of the creation of the branch on which I made my commits.

I inadvertently created my new branch from the `Master` branch, and I should have created it from the Hotfix branch, because that's the branch to which I'm going to do the PR on the original repo.

So those extra commits showing there are the difference between the `master` and the `hotfix` branch.

On the web interface, to control from which branch a new branch is created, simply:

1. In the Code tab, change to the branch from which to want to create a new branch
2. On the same dropdown, start typing a new branch name and Github will offer to create a sub-branch from there.